# Fuzzy objects when in front of each other (THREE.JS)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was messing around with three.js and I have run into a problem with objects that are in front of one another. The objects get all fuzzy, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qer00.png). Could anyone aid me in this? The code (crappy, albeit working) is:

```
 //////////////////////////////////
//      Init basic objects      //
//////////////////////////////////
var scene;
var renderer;
var camera;

var backgroundScene;
var backgroundCamera;



//////////////////////////////////
//    Init supporting modules   //
//////////////////////////////////
//Initialize the top-left stats screen
var stats;
//Initialize the axes.
var axis;
//Used for getting the camera option (inputed by user)
var cameraMode = 1; //0 - follow, 1 - toXAxis, 2 - toCenter, 3 - followHorizontal


//////////////////////////////////
//     Time and acceleration    //
//////////////////////////////////
var milis = 0;
var scale = 170;
var acceleration = 10000 * scale;
var acceleratedTime;


//////////////////////////////////
//   Init objects, def consts   //
//////////////////////////////////
//Sun
//Constants
const SUN_ANGULAR_ROTAION = 2.865329607243705e-6; //in [rad/s]
const SUN_RADIUS = 696342000 * scale; //in [m]
const SUN_MERIDIANS_AND_PARALLELS = 80; //in []
//Objects
var sunGeo;
var sunMat;
var sun;

var sunLight;


//Earth
//Constants
const EARTH_ANGULAR_ROTATION = 7.292115053925690e-5; //in [rad/s]
const EARTH_RADIUS = 6368500 * scale; //in [m]
const EARTH_MERIDIANS_AND_PARALLELS = 80; //in []
const EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS = 1.4960e11; //in [m]
const EARTH_ANGULAR_REVOLUTION = 1.99102128e-7; //in [rad/s]
const EARTH_YEAR_LENGTH = 31.6e6;
const EARTH_AXIAL_TILT = 0.13022222222 * Math.PI; //in [rad]
//Objects
var earthGeo;
var earthMat;
var earth;


//Ecliptic Axis
//Objects
var eclipticAxisGeo;
var eclipticAxisMat;
var eclipticAxis;



//Start the actual code
function init() { //Initializes
    //////////////////////////////////
    //    Creating basic objects    //
    //////////////////////////////////
    //Create scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //Init renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000, 1.0));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    //Init camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(42, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, EARTH_RADIUS * 100);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //   Create supporting modules  //
    //////////////////////////////////
    stats = new Stats();
    stats = initStats();

    axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(100000000000000);
    scene.add(axis);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //    Creating the Background   //
    //////////////////////////////////
    //Material
    var backgroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    backgroundMaterial.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("resources/textures/sky.jpg");

    //Mesh
    var background = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 2), backgroundMaterial);

    //Mesh position and rotation
    background.rotation.z += Math.PI / 2;

    //Material editing
    background.material.depthTest = false;
    background.material.depthWrite = false;

    //Scene
    backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
    backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();

    //Add objects
    backgroundScene.add(background);
    backgroundScene.add(backgroundCamera);

    //////////////////////////////////
    //       Creating the Sun       //
    //////////////////////////////////
    //Geometry
    sunGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(SUN_RADIUS, SUN_MERIDIANS_AND_PARALLELS, SUN_MERIDIANS_AND_PARALLELS);

    //Material
    sunMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    sunMat.emissive = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    sunMat.emissiveMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("resources/textures/sun.jpg");

    //Mesh creation
    sun = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeo, sunMat);

    //Position of the Sun
    sun.position.x = 0;
    sun.position.y = 0;
    sun.position.z = 0;

    //Adding the sun
    scene.add(sun);

    //Adding light from sun
    sunLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.0, 0);
    sunLight.position.x = 0;
    sunLight.position.y = 0;
    sunLight.position.z = 0;
    scene.add(sunLight);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //      Creating the Earth      //
    //////////////////////////////////
    //Geometry
    earthGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(EARTH_RADIUS, EARTH_MERIDIANS_AND_PARALLELS, EARTH_MERIDIANS_AND_PARALLELS);

    //Material
    earthMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    earthMat.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("resources/textures/earth.jpg");

    //Mesh creation
    earth = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeo, earthMat);

    //Position of the Earth
    earth.position.x = EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS;
    earth.position.y = 0;
    earth.position.z = 0;

    //Rotate the Earth properly
    earth.rotation.y = Math.Pi / 2;
    earth.rotation.z += EARTH_AXIAL_TILT;

    //Adding the Earth
    scene.add(earth);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //  Creating the EclipticAxis   //
    //////////////////////////////////
    //Geometry
    eclipticAxisGeo = new THREE.CircleGeometry(EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS, 10000);
    eclipticAxisGeo.vertices.shift();

    //Material
    eclipticAxisMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xFF00FF
    });


    //Mesh creation
    eclipticAxis = new THREE.Line(eclipticAxisGeo, eclipticAxisMat);

    //Rotate the Ecliptic properly
    eclipticAxis.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

    //Adding the Ecliptic
    scene.add(eclipticAxis);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //      Camera positioning      //
    //////////////////////////////////
    camera.position.set(earth.position.x, earth.position.y, earth.position.z);
    camera.position.y += 1000000000 * scale;
    camera.position.z += 1000000000 * scale;
    camera.lookAt(earth.position);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //     Appending to the DOM     //
    //////////////////////////////////
    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);



    //////////////////////////////////
    // Creating interval functions  //
    //////////////////////////////////
    setInterval(function() {
        ++milis;
        acceleratedTime = milis * acceleration / 1000; //TODO: Fix this bodge
    }, 1);



    //////////////////////////////////
    //Calling the actual renderScene//
    //////////////////////////////////  
    renderScene();
};



function renderScene() { //Does the rendering
    stats.update();

    /*      COPE WITH ROTATION      */
    sun.rotation.y = SUN_ANGULAR_ROTAION * acceleratedTime;

    earth.rotation.y = EARTH_ANGULAR_ROTATION * acceleratedTime;



    /*      COPE WITH REVOLUTION    */
    //The Sun doesn't move as its position is 0, 0, 0

    earth.position.x = Math.cos(EARTH_ANGULAR_REVOLUTION * acceleratedTime) * EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS;
    earth.position.z = Math.sin(-EARTH_ANGULAR_REVOLUTION * acceleratedTime) * EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS;



    /*      COPE WITH CAMERA        */
    //TODO: Work with cameraMode0 and cameraMode3
    if (cameraMode == 0) {
        camera.position.x = earth.position.x + 10000000 * scale;
        camera.position.y = earth.position.y + 10000000 * scale;
        camera.position.z = earth.position.z + 10000000 * scale;

        camera.lookAt(earth.position);
    } else if (cameraMode == 1) { //To Starting Position
        camera.position.x = EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS;
        camera.position.y = 1000000000 * scale;
        camera.position.z = 1000000000 * scale;

        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(EARTH_SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS, 0, 0));
    } else if (cameraMode == 2) { //To Center
        camera.position.x = sun.position.x;
        camera.position.y = sun.position.y + SUN_RADIUS * scale / 50;
        camera.position.z = sun.position.z;

        camera.lookAt(sun.position);
    } else {
        camera.position.x = earth.position.x;
        camera.position.y = 0;
        camera.position.z = 0;

        camera.lookAt(earth.position);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(renderScene); //The ugly bits

    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(backgroundScene, backgroundCamera);
    renderer.render(scene, camera); //The ugly bits
};


//////////////////////////////////
//Initiates the supporting stats//
//////////////////////////////////
function initStats() {
    stats.setMode(0);

    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

    document.getElementById("Stats-output").appendChild(stats.domElement);

    return stats;
};


//////////////////////////////////
//Defines what happens on resize//
//////////////////////////////////
function onResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's an issue with the depth buffer. There's a great example [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer) of the difference between logarithmic and linear z buffer. They recommend using the logarithmic z buffer for great distances. It looks like you're modeling planets,so I think this might be the source of your sorrows.

Take a look at this example and see if your issue looks similar to the left side (normal z buffer) of this sketch, and if so, you probably simply need to use a logarithmic z buffer as per my linked example above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why, thank you! This is much better and it's actually not as buggy.

Sadly, this has created two new problems.

The first is the fact that my static background is gone.

And the second is that the line I have created around the Sun is still intersecting the Sun. It's not intersecting the Earth anymore, though.

Comment: Here's an image: [image](http://i.imgur.com/X7bhbnF.png) - notice the top-left hand corner.